# How should I design my databas for online voting web app?

Tags: database-design, schema

Currently I'm trying to build web app for online voting where registered user can create their own Election.
For the database, every time user create an election should the system create new required table for the election or I could just some tables to hold everything ?

1. case 1 (create required table for each election ) :

- user_table (id,name,email,etc)
- election_table (user_id,
  election_id,etc)

per election created by user above, below tables will be created in database with electionId is part of table name :

- voter_electionId_table (voter_id,name,email,etc)
- candidate_electionId_table (candidate_id,no,name)
- ballot_electionId_table(vote_id,candidate_id)

example expected result : [image]

1. case 2 ( same tables for every election) :
2. user_table (id,name,email,etc)
3. election_table (user_id,
   election_id,etc)
4. voter_table(voter_id,election_id,etc)
5. candidate_table (electionID,candidate_id,no,name,etc)
6. ballot_table(electionId,vote_id,candidate_id)

expected result : [image]

which from above is better ? or none of them is good (If yes, please share your thought).

Comment: Telle me if I understand it correctly. You are asking yourself: should I keep the same database for every election or should I re-create a database for every new election? You are asking if you want to reuse the database, right?

Comment: Sorry for poor English, but what I mean was should I keep all the record for all very election in the same tables or should I replicate required table for every new election.

Answer (score 0):

You question is:

*should I keep all the record for all very election in the same tables or should I replicate required table for every new election.*

This is a question about data security.

If you keep all the data you will end up by keeping the historic of what a people voted for the next 25 years.

What is your data policy retention?

Should you do that? I don't know, you have to ask to the people that are asking you to create this database.

Comment: i've just edited my post. By using replicated table I was thinking I could drop the table later on 7 days or 30 days period after required election table created. And also it's useless to ask the client about db design.

Comment: @xedox_za, if this has to be a voting website why don't you just use WordPress with a dedicated plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/epoll-wp-voting/

Comment: It seems like we are reinventing the wheel here. Both solutions are OK for me.

Comment: I've made app from scratch for Chairman Election for an organization, but it was design to be used for that election only. I want to broaden the feature so the app can be used for many Election. What I really do not know is how to design the db and what might the pro and con of the db schema that I design.